# Nesting of test commands (IfStrEq, IfSubStr etc.) of xstring

Tags: conditionals, expansion, xstring

The following code does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\checkempty[1]{
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{%
        Empty
    }{%
        NonEmpty
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \checkempty{\IfStrEq{justadummyvalue}{justadummyvalue}{somevalue}{}}
\end{document}
```

[Edit:
What I expect with `\checkempty{\IfStrEq{a}{a}{val}{}}` is `NonEmpty`. However, `\checkempty{\IfStrEq{a}{b}{val}{}}` shall result in `Empty`.
]

However, I get some errors like

```
Argument of \@xs@expand@and@assign has an extra }. \firstif{a}{b}{c} (followed by: )    document.tex    /test   line 19 Texlipse Build Error
```

and finally also this

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=65000]. \firstif{a}{b}{c} (followed by: )    document.tex    /test   line 19 Texlipse Build Error
```

Basically, I can guess the problem. `\IfStrEq` cannot be expanded (or however this phenomenon is called exactly) and cannot be nested. Therefore, most commands in `xstring` provide a syntax like `\StrLeft{xstring}{4}[\Result]`. The result string is stored in `\Result` then.

However, test commands do not provide this syntax, and I also guess that it would not be meaningful. However, I still hope that there are some tweaks to get my example working.

Please tell me, if there is a tweak I can put inside of `\checkempty`.
I need to determine (via any case of `if`) inside of a command (here `\checkempty`), if the passed argument (expanded) is empty or not.
[Edit: The outer `IfStrEq` shall be expanded before!]
If there is no tweak, I cannot use `IfStrEq`, right?

In past I worked with the `xifthen` package. It was a complete pain, and I could not manage some expansion problem. With `xstring` and `IfSubStr` everything worked fine, except in the case I am showing in my example :(

Answer (score 11):

The `xstring` package offers extra (read: advanced) options to control the expansion of the arguments. This is really not meant for beginners and a good understanding of how arguments are expanded is more than welcome.

In your case the code can be tweaked to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\checkempty[1]{
    \normalexpandarg
    \exploregroups
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{%
        Empty
    }{%
        NonEmpty
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \checkempty{\IfStrEq{justadummyvalue}{justadummyvalue}{somevalue}{}}
\end{document}
```

Notice the two new lines in the declaration of `\checkempty`. The first, `\normalexpandarg` ensures that the arguments (the strings to be compared) passed to `\IfStrEq` are not fully expanded, as they would by default (`xstring` is set by default to `fullexpandarg`). However, if your argument contains braces, the invoked `xstring` command will not look inside that group. Since you want to check whether arguments passed to your command are empty or not, this check should still be done, hence the `\exploregroups` line. (If you don't want to use this feature, simply leave out that line.) You can revert at any time to the default behavior with `\noexploregroups`.

These toggles can be used at any place within your code and can be made local by scoping.

Hope that helps. `:)`

Comment: I have slightly edited my question, maybe it was ambiguous. What I expect with `\checkempty{\IfStrEq{a}{a}{val}{}}` is `NonEmpty`. However, `\checkempty{\IfStrEq{a}{b}{val}{}}` shall result in `Empty`. I checked the code above, but I always get `NonEmpty`, except with `\checkempty{}`, of course.

Comment: So you basically want `\IfStrEq{a}{b}{NonEmpty}{Empty}`? Because IMO from your comment that's what it finally boils down to.

Comment: That would also be my (late) comment. :)

Comment: You are right, but as I said the code inside `document` shall remain untouched. My real latex code is much more complicated than in the example, so I really need the expansion. No matter, if the example is meaningful or not ;)

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, I shall mention that LaTeX3 makes use of the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive (or equivalents for `XeTeX` and `LuaTeX`) to compare strings expandably.  Note that `xstring` has a weird definition of what a string is (which I don't want to investigate now), so if you are using advanced features, it may not be possible to directly translate to LaTeX3 lingo.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfStrEq \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\checkempty[1]{
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{%
        Empty
    }{%
        NonEmpty
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \checkempty{\IfStrEq{justadummyvalue}{justadummyvalue}{somevalue}{}}
\end{document}
```

EDIT after some thought: Actually, in the code above I define `\IfStrEq` as a copy of `\str_if_eq:nnTF`, but it is probably better to introduce a new command, `\expandableIfStrEq` (or whatever), because `\IfStrEq` gives other possibilities (depending on the presence of a star).